# android studio's virtual device is not running

Tags: android, android-studio, android-emulator, virtual-machine

Here is the error

> Cannot launch AVD in emulator.
>       Output:
>       PANIC: HOME is defined but could not find Nexus_5_API_11_2.ini file in $HOME.android\avd (Note: avd is searched in the order of $ANDROID_AVD_HOME,$ANDROID_SDK_HOME.android\avd and
>   $HOME.android\avd)

Comment: Please read - http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

This is not actually a fix to your error but I think you should consider using genymotion's virtual device. It's very nice. Check it out here https://www.genymotion.com/#!/